# Angular $resource then not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have this simple app witha factory and a controller:

```
angular.module('AppName', ['ngResource'])

.factory('apiData', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var apiRequest = $resource("https://live.reddcoin.com/api/addr/:address/balance");
    return {
        full: function(address){
            return apiRequest.get({address: address}).$promise
            .then(
                function(data){ console.log(data); return data;},
                function(){ return 'error'; }
            );
        }
        }
}])

.controller('TwoController', function($scope, apiData){
    $scope.price = apiData.full('RszZrK51ur5G67y3Wy6niTnawdYYdBRZEq').then(function(data){console.log(data); return data;});
});
```

The then sections in both factory and controller not returning data from the api resource. Instead it returns `e { $promise=Promise,  $resolved=true,  toJSON=function(),  more...}` as can be seen in the console.

The url from the example api resource: 
https://live.reddcoin.com/api/addr/RszZrK51ur5G67y3Wy6niTnawdYYdBRZEq/balance

[And the example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/qgho1veL/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `$resource` doesn't include data(not in object format) inside object return by promise, It display result like below

```
e {$promise: Promise, $resolved: true} // 1003021043401956 isn't included there
```

I think get request is expecting object returned from the server. So if it doesn't return an object, then it will not include the same in response

There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. Do return data in object format like `{'data': '1003021043401956'}`
2. Create your own `get` request object inside resource, that will modify before it returns promise object.

   ```
   var apiRequest = $resource("https://live.reddcoin.com/api/addr/:address/balance", {}, {
      get: {
         method: 'GET',
         transformResponse: function(response){
            return {data: response}; //creating object
         }
      }
   });
   ```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/30mcxtqq/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.controller('TwoController', function($scope, apiData){
    apiData.full('RszZrK51ur5G67y3Wy6niTnawdYYdBRZEq').then(function(data){
        console.log(data); 
        $scope.price = data;
    });
});
```

Remember that promises are chained. So eventhough you return `data` in the success callback, the result of `then` is still a promise (with `data` as the inner result).

Working code snippet:

```js
angular.module('AppName', ['ngResource'])

.factory('apiData', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var apiRequest = $resource("https://live.reddcoin.com/api/addr/:address/balance");
    return {
        full: function(address){
            return apiRequest.get({address: address}).$promise
            .then(
                function(data){ console.log(data); return data;},
                function(){ return 'error'; }
            );
        }
        }
}])

.controller('TwoController', function($scope, apiData){
    apiData.full('RszZrK51ur5G67y3Wy6niTnawdYYdBRZEq').then(function(data){console.log(data); $scope.price =  data;});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="AppName" ng-controller="TwoController">{{price}}</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but `data` should be the returned data from the resolved promise, isn't it?

Comment: exactly, but you cannot return data within the 'then' success callback, and assign the result of 'then' to the scope. The result of 'then' is always a promise. The only way to assign the data itself to the scope, is to assign the scope variable within the then success callback.

Comment: Got it, but `console.log(data);` in the success callback still don't show me in the console the data I need. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @fikkatra you know, even if OP do this `$scope.price = apiData.full('RszZrK51ur5G67y3Wy6niTnawdYYdBRZEq')` should work Ideally.. There is no need to have `.then` to wait till data comes up..